# An inequality of integral on [0,1] relative to Fourier transform.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

For $\alpha > 0$, I want to prove that there exists a positive number $C$ s.t. the following inequality holds.
$$ \int_0^1 (1-t)^{\alpha} cos(2 \pi xt) dt \leq \frac{C}{(1+|x|)^{min \{ 1+\alpha , 2 \} } }$$
I can't find any relation between Riemann-Lebesgue theorem for fourier transform on [0,1] and this inequality, but there is a hint that using the proof of it.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very similar argument to Van der Corput's Lemma (which is really just integration by parts to force the decay). I'll do a sketch, omitting some computations.

First, notice that it's enough to consider $x>0$ since $\cos$ is even. Moreover, since $|\cos(y)|\leq 1$ and $\int_0^1(1-t)^\alpha\, dt= c_\alpha<\infty$, it's enough to prove the bound for $x>1$.

First, do a change of variables (and use that $\cos$ is even again) to write
$$
f(x):=\int_0^1 (1-t)^\alpha \cos(2\pi xt)\, dt = \int_0^1 t^\alpha \cos(2\pi x(t-1))\, dt.
$$
Now integrate by parts, after multiplying and dividing by $2\pi x$, to get
$$
f(x)= \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi x}\int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1} \sin(2\pi x(t-1))\, dt.
$$
Now if $\alpha=1$ we can evaluate this directly and get the right bound; on the other hand if $\alpha>1$, then we can integrate by parts again in the same way to get the bound by $x^{-2}$. Therefore it remains the case $0<\alpha<1$, and recall that we're using $x>1$. For this we break up the integral above
$$
f(x)= \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi x} \int_0^{1/x} t^{\alpha-1} \sin(2\pi x(t-1))\, dt + \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi x}\int_{1/x}^1 t^{\alpha-1} \sin(2\pi x(t-1))\, dt =I+II.
$$
To handle $I$ we just use the trivial bound for $\sin$,
$$
|I|\leq \dfrac{\alpha}{2\pi x}\int_{0}^{1/x} t^{\alpha-1}\, dt  \leq \dfrac{1}{2\pi x^{1+\alpha}}.
$$
To deal with with $II$, we integrate by parts as in the very first step to get a similar bound as in $I$.